# Touch command in Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, unix, touch

I am having confusion in touch command
while i execute "touch -m 0303 10 30 filename" it should actually update the modification time to 
03 - march
03 - date
10 hours
30 - min 
But while executing it is creating 5 empty files 
named 03 03 10 30 filename
I executed this command in OSX

Comment: You are not familiar with man?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command line, Instead of taking the current time-stamp, you can explicitly specify the time using -t flag.

The format for specifying -t is `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]`

```
touch -m -t 03041030 filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Read `man touch` again. `-m` doesn't take any arguments, you have to add `-t` or `-d` (I'm not sure whether both options are available on OSX).